# Adding values to a vector until the user inputs 0 in C++?

Tags: c++

How do I structure my while loop so that it will keep accepting int values until the user enter 0?

I have

```
while(cin >> integers && integers != 0){
    numbers.push_back(integers);
    if(integers == 0){
        break;
    }
}
```

but it keeps crashing on me.

Edit:

```
int integers;
    int fox;
    vector<int> numbers;
    cout << "Please enter in integers (0 to stop): ";
    while(cin >> integers){
        numbers.push_back(integers);
        if(integers == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    int y = numbers.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < y; y++){
        cout << numbers.at(y) << " ";
    }
```

Comment: You already check for it being 0 in the loop condition. Putting it inside the body is pointless. Anyway, there's no way just this code crashed.

Comment: It is still giving me a debug error when I try to print out the elements of the vector.  :(

Comment: If it's crashing, something else is going on.  Show us all of your code, i.e., the declaration of `integers` and `numbers`.

Comment: could you post your program?

Comment: @user3024476: Then perhaps you should show us that code...

Comment: "it keeps crashing on me" -> Where? With what error? Under which conditions?

Comment: Edited, it gives a debug error and abort() has been called at R6010 in Visual Studio.

Comment: Well now your first loop us just wrong.  You add 0 to the vector and *then* exit the loop.  The first version was better, just remove the dead code (the if statement)

Comment: You should get a warning (not sure if MSVC does it) about a signed/unsigned comparison. `y` should be a `std::vector<int>::size_type` to ensure it's the same type as the result of `size()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` should be `i`. You're accessing the vector out-of-bounds. Also `y++` should be `i++`, otherwise you will have an infinite loop.

```
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {
    cout << numbers.at(i) << " ";
}
```

`operator[]` does not have bounds checking, so `at` is actually a bit safer in this regard.

Visual Studio was probably either `abort`ing because of your infinite loop, or because you had an `out_of_range` exception that went uncaught. For example, it might look like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

  what():  vector::_M_range_check
```

It is unnecessary, but you can wrap your code in a try-catch block.

```
try
{
    std::cout << members.at(members.size());
} catch(std::out_of_range& ex)
{
    std::cout << "Out of range error: " << ex.what() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on your question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        vector<int> numbers;
        int integers;
       while(cin >> integers && integers != 0){
        numbers.push_back(integers);

        }

        for( int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << numbers[i] << ' ';

       return 0;
    }
```

After seeing your edited question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int integers;
    int fox;
    vector<int> numbers;
    cout << "Please enter in integers (0 to stop): ";
    while(cin >> integers){
        if(integers == 0){
            break;
        }
        numbers.push_back(integers);  //Moved after the check to not inclue 0

    }
    int y = numbers.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }

   return 0;
}
```